# Node.js - Find parameter in array nested in JSON object and return other parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object, nested

I have an API call in Node.js which is returning a JSON object.

I need to find in this object a customer phone number (preferably by function), with `body.result.reservations[X of reserv.].client.phone`, and return parameters `phone`, `dateFrom` and `dateTo`, preferably to an array, with `body.result.reservations[X number].reservationDetails.dateFrom` and so on.

Accessing those parameters works through adding dots but when I try to use any search algorithm from the internet it crashes with undefined, .phone is not a function and other fancy things.

This is the output from `console.log(body.result.reservations)`:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        reservationDetails:
            {
                price: 670,
                dateFrom: '2019-03-29 13:59',
                dateTo: '2019-04-05 19:00',
                status: 'waiting'
            }
    },

    {   id: 2,
        reservationDetails:
            { price: 4500,
                dateFrom: '2019-04-09 20:00',
                dateTo: '2019-05-18 12:00',
                status: 'accepted',
                },
        client:
            {   id: 8,
                login: 'customer@x.com',
                clientType: 'person',
                phone: '+5.500500500',
                } 
     },
     {   id: 4,
        reservationDetails:
            { price: 9500,
                dateFrom: '2020-04-09 13:00',
                dateTo: '2020-04-18 10:00',
                status: 'passed',
                },
        client:
            {   id: 8,
                login: 'customer2@x2.com',
                clientType: 'person',
                phone: '+38.700500500',
                } 
     }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because not all entries in the array has the client property and therefore no phone number. This solution gives you an array of all reservations with either the phone number or phone number as 'missing phone number' in case its missing.

```
    const body = {
      result: {
        reservations: [
          {
            id: 1,
            reservationDetails:
            {
              price: 670,
              dateFrom: '2019-03-29 13:59',
              dateTo: '2019-04-05 19:00',
              status: 'waiting'
            }
          },

          {
            id: 2,
            reservationDetails:
            {
              price: 4500,
              dateFrom: '2019-04-09 20:00',
              dateTo: '2019-05-18 12:00',
              status: 'accepted',
            },
            client:
            {
              id: 8,
              login: 'customer@x.com',
              clientType: 'person',
              phone: '+5.500500500',
            }
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            reservationDetails:
            {
              price: 9500,
              dateFrom: '2020-04-09 13:00',
              dateTo: '2020-04-18 10:00',
              status: 'passed',
            },
            client:
            {
              id: 8,
              login: 'customer2@x2.com',
              clientType: 'person',
              phone: '+38.700500500',
            }
          }]
      }
    } 


      const reservations = body.result.reservations.map((reservation) => {
        return {
          dateFrom : reservation.reservationDetails.dateFrom,
          dateTo: reservation.reservationDetails.dateTo,
          phone: reservation.client ? reservation.client.phone : 'missing phone number'
        }
       });
```

Comment: You've saved my day, it works great - I just had to add .find() to find proper reservation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.find`:

```js
const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        reservationDetails:
        {
            price: 670,
            dateFrom: '2019-03-29 13:59',
            dateTo: '2019-04-05 19:00',
            status: 'waiting'
        }
    },

    {
        id: 2,
        reservationDetails:
        {
            price: 4500,
            dateFrom: '2019-04-09 20:00',
            dateTo: '2019-05-18 12:00',
            status: 'accepted',
        },
        client:
        {
            id: 8,
            login: 'customer@x.com',
            clientType: 'person',
            phone: '+5.500500500',
        }
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        reservationDetails:
        {
            price: 9500,
            dateFrom: '2020-04-09 13:00',
            dateTo: '2020-04-18 10:00',
            status: 'passed',
        },
        client:
        {
            id: 8,
            login: 'customer2@x2.com',
            clientType: 'person',
            phone: '+38.700500500',
        }
    }]
    
function findPhone(phone, data){
  const result = data.find(e => e.client ? e.client.phone === phone : null);
  return result ? result : 'No match found';
}

console.log(findPhone('+38.700500500', data));
console.log(findPhone('11111', data));
```

This will return the matched object or a 'No match found'.